# CMake Error at build: Missing item in FREETYPE_LIBRARY

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, sfml, freetype

I am trying to install a tester program (https://github.com/o-reo/push_swap_visualizer) on my Microsoft Visual Code running on wsl-ubuntu.
The developer of the program says that in order to install, I need to clone the program from a github and then run the command "cmake ..."
Also this tester programs requires C++17, cmake, SFML and ImGui.
When I run "cmake ..." I get an error message:

```
-- Fetching ImGui-SFML...
-- Found ImGui v1.82 in /home/aputiev/projects/03/push_swap_test/push_swap_visualizer/build/_deps/imgui-src
-- Fetching SFML...
-- libudev stable: 0
-- Found UDev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so
--    include: /usr/include
CMake Error at build/_deps/sfml-src/cmake/Macros.cmake:296 (message):
  Missing item in FREETYPE_LIBRARY
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  build/_deps/sfml-src/src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeLists.txt:137 (sfml_find_package)
```

Also I installed cmake and SFML. And libssl-dev library with "sudo apt install libssl-dev"
I am completely new to programming. Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

installing of libfreetype-dev helped